# Bower: replace the latest dependency version by its actual number

Tags: javascript, bower

My bower.json:

```
{
  "...." : "...."
  "name": "myproject",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.20",
    "bootstrap": "latest"
  }
}
```

I'd like to replace "latest" in bootstrap dependency by its actual version number. Is there any way to do that via bower command ? (not via a custom script)

Comment: Just had a look at this and there doesn't appear to be a direct way. I had assumed `bower install --save bootstrap` would have worked but it replaced the `latest` with `*` which is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

No, bower doesn't have shrinkwrap feature.

It is a long-standing issue: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/505